# Why is the usage of " but" different in these two sentences?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, morphology

1. He did nothing at all ***but*** repeatedly ***brag*** what he has done for the country.
2. I had no choice ***but to give up*** the offer.

Why is " but" in above examples respectively followed by a bare infinitive and an infinitive with to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because of what came before as the verb of the sentence. For the first sentence it is "did", and for the second it is "had".

So if you take out the middle part, the sentences become:

1. He did (nothing at all but repeatedly) brag what he has done for the country.
2. I had (no choice but) to give up the offer.

Comment: It looks interesting. Here is another example, " He had nothing to do but watch movies."

Comment: In that sentence, they omitted a "to" in front of "watch movies". The full sentence goes "He had nothing to do but (to) watch movies."